# Java: Strategy pattern with access to superclass' fields and methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have an abstract class `Parent` with abstract methods `foo()` and `bar()` and other non-abstract methods and fields. I need to create 4 subclasses (and later more) to cover each combination of different variations on `foo()` and `bar()`: `fooA()`, `fooB()`, `barA()`, `barB()`. These variations need access to other fields and methods of `Parent`.
In other words, if Java supported multiple inheritance, then I would have something like:

```
abstract class Parent{
    abstract foo(){}
    abstract bar(){}
    //other fields and methods that will be accessed foo and bar are PROTECTED
}

abstract class FooA extends Parent{
    @Override
    foo(){ ... }
}
abstract class FooB extends Parent{
    @Override
    foo(){ ... }
}
abstract class BarA extends Parent{
    @Override
    bar(){ ... }
}
abstract class BarB extends Parent{
    @Override
    bar(){ ... }
}

class ChildAA extends FooA, BarA{   
}

class ChildAB extends FooA, BarB{
}

class ChildBA extends FooB, BarA{
}

class ChildBB extends FooB, BarB{
}
```

I have found two solutions, each of which sort of works, but just about. Are there better ways to achieve this behaviour? My solutions are as follows:

1) First solution:

```
abstract class Parent {
    foo(){ 
        /* behaves like fooA */
    }
    //other fields and methods that will be accessed foo and bar are PROTECTED
}

class ChildAA extends Parent{
    barA(){ ... }
}

class ChildAB extends Parent{
    barB(){ ... }
}

class ChildBA extends ChildAA{
    @Override
    foo(){ /* behaves like fooB */ }
|

class ChildBB extends ChildAB{
    @Override 
    foo(){ /* behaves like fooB */ }
}
```

The problem with this is that it duplicates the code for `fooB()` and all additional methods that only `fooB()` needs. The problem gets exponentially worse when more variations are needed.

2) After looking around I found the design pattern Strategy, which can be used to achieve the behaviour but is awkward because the variations need to access `Parent`'s fields and methods:

```
abstract class Parent{
    Fooable fooable;
    Barable barable;
    foo(){ fooable.foo(); }
    bar(){ barable.bar(); }
    //other fields and methods that will be accessed foo and bar are PUBLIC
}

abstract class ImplementableParent{
    Parent p;
    ImplementableParent(Parent p) { this.p = p; }
}

interface Fooable{
    foo();
}
class FooA extends ImplementableParent implements Fooable{
    FooA(Parent p){ super(p); }
    @Override 
    foo(){ /* behaves like FooA */ }
}
class FooB extends ImplementableParent implements Fooable{
    FooB(Parent p){ super(p); }
    @Override 
    foo(){ /* behaves like FooB */ }
}

interface Barable{
    bar();
}
class BarA extends ImplementableParent implements Barable{
    BarA(Parent p) { super(p); }
    @Override 
    bar() { /* behaves like BarA */ }
}
class BarB extends ImplementableParent implements Barable{
    BarB(Parent p) { super(p); }
    @Override 
    bar() { /* behaves like BarB */ }
}

class ChildAA extends Parent{
    fooable = new FooA(this);
    barable = new BarA(this);
}

class ChildAB extends Parent{
    fooable = new FooA(this);
    barable = new BarB(this);
}

class ChildBA extends Parent{
    fooable = new FooB(this);
    barable = new BarA(this);
}

class ChildBB extends Parent{
    fooable = new FooB(this);
    barable = new BarB(this);
}
```

This gets rid of repetitions of variations and can be extended to accommodate more variations. However, now the fields and methods of `Parent` are public and the whole thing feels very convoluted. I am also concerned about performance overhead, since `FooA`, `FooB`, `BarA` and `BarB` access the `Parent` methods indirectly, although I haven't tested it.

Is there a better way to achieve the behaviour?

Comment: Did you evaluate the option of passing the needed fields in Parent as parameters to `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: Why do you use an abstract class rather than interfaces?

Comment: If not using interfaces like Fooable and Barable, maybe define Parent as abstract. Then define Child with some String parameter (e.g. "AA", AB", "BA", "BB") and multiplex the implementation of foo() and bar()  accordingly using a switch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying too much on inheritance IMO. A general rule of Clean Code is prefer composition over inheritance.

What you want is something like this:

```
interface Foo {
    void foo();
}
interface Bar {
    void bar();
}
interface FooBar extends Foo, Bar {}
```

There are several ways to create this.

**Inner classes and factory methods in the Parent class**

The `Parent` class doesn't need to implement those; it can provide inner classes doing that, so that those are able to access the protected members.

```
class Parent {
    protected int neededByFoo;
    protected int neededByBar;

    class FooA implements Foo {
        public void foo() {
            doStuffWithNeededByFoo();
        }
    }
    class FooB implements Foo {
        public void foo() {
            doStuffWithNeededByFoo();
        }
    }
    // same for the BarA and BarB implementations
}
```

With the help of a utility delegate class (not unlike your solution B) and factory methods in `Parent`, you can combine them into the instances implementing both interfaces.

```
    private static class FooBarDelegate implements FooBar {
        Foo fooDelegate;
        Bar barDelegate;
        private FooBarDelegate(Foo f, Bar b) { fooDelegate = f; barDelegate = b; }
        public void foo() { fooDelegate.foo(); }
        public void bar() { barDelegate.bar(); }
    }

    public FooBar fooAbarA() {
        return new FooBarDelegate(new FooA(), new BarA());
    }
    public FooBar fooBbarA() {
        return new FooBarDelegate(new FooB(), new BarA());
    }
    public FooBar fooAbarB() {
        return new FooBarDelegate(new FooA(), new BarB());
    }
    public FooBar fooBbarA() {
        return new FooBarDelegate(new FooB(), new BarB());
    }
}
```

[Here's a running version of this code](https://ideone.com/Hj4D65).

Now, the inner classes are essentially the strategies being assembled into a `FooBar` instance. There's no need to subclass `Parent` at all.

**Using a combine method in the interface**

You might not want to do the combining in the `Parent` class at all, but in the interface:

```
interface FooBar extends Foo, Bar {
    public static FooBar combine(Foo f, Bar b) {
        return new FooBar() {
            foo() { f.foo(); }
            bar() { b.bar(); }
        }
    }
}
```

which you'd then use like this

```
Parent p = new Parent();
FooBar fb = FooBar.combine(new p.FooA(), new p.BarA());
fb = FooBar.combine(new p.FooA(), new p.BarB());
```

and so on.

**Method references**

Because `Foo` and `Bar` are functional interfaces, you could combine methods of a `Parent` object rather than using inner classes.

```
class Parent {
    public void fooA() { // do stuff }
    public void fooB() { // do stuff }
    public void barA() { // do stuff }
    public void barB() { // do stuff }
}
```

and then

```
FooBar fb = FooBar.combine(p::fooA, p::barA);
fb = FooBar.combine(p::fooA, p::barB);
// and so on
```

[Like this](https://ideone.com/fnBlAk).

Comment: That is a lot of new information for me, - I think I can incorporate this into my design, - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> However, now the fields and methods of Parent are public and the whole
>   thing feels very convoluted.

Your Barable and Fooable implementations don't hold the context themselves, so they necessarily have to use `public` methods from the context object (subclasses `Parent` here) to query and manipulate it.
But only `Parent` methods have to be public, not its fields.

For example that would be a fair implementation for `Parent` and the `FooA` implementation :

```
abstract class Parent{

    private Fooable fooable;  // internals 
    private Barable barable;  // internals

    private String sharedString;  // internals
    private Integer sharedInteger;  // internals

    // public access        
    public foo(){ fooable.foo(); }
    public bar(){ barable.bar(); }

    public String getSharedString(){
        return sharedString;
    }

    public Integer getSharedInteger(){
        return sharedInteger;
    }

    public String updateSharedData(String string, Integer integer){
        // apply some logic and controls if required
        this.string = string;
        this.integer = integer;
    }

}


class FooA extends ImplementableParent implements Fooable{
    FooA(Parent p){ 
       super(p); 
    }
    @Override 
    foo(){  
        if (p.getSharedString().equals("...)){
           // some logic
           p.updateSharedData("new value", newIntegerValue);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note defining `Parent` as a dependency of wrapped `Fooable` and `Barable` instances  mean that  a `Fooable` can manipulate a `Barable` and reversely.
That is not stated in your actual requirement. If you want to prevent that, you should define a specific class for the context that contains the data and the methods you want to share between the two kinds of contract (`Fooable` and `Barable`) and another class for the general contract of ChildXXX subclasses.
And instead of passing a `Parent` instance in the constructor you would pass a `Context` instance.